# What do these symbols in manga mean?

Tags: manga, orthography, punctuation, symbols

In the manga Shinya no Dame Koizukan (深夜のダメ恋図鑑), I spotted four different symbols (marked in red in the picture). The Ψ symbol is even repeated a few times, but I can't figure out what it means.

I've tried searching up Japanese symbols and have gone through Wikipedia's [List of Japanese typographic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Japanese_typographic_symbols) etc. but I can't seem to find the following symbols anywhere. What do they mean? Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: They look like Greek, but from the context, I believe the speech should be in Gifu dialect and there shouldn't be any Greek used :(

[image]

Comment: I don't know ones in the middle though, the others seem like π and Ψ. It’s all Greek to me in Japanese sentence.

Comment: Are you reading this online or on an e-reader?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems to be an encoding/typesetting issue and the "symbols" are indeed Greek letters Ψ, Π, π that seem to be displayed instead of `!`, `?`, `〜`.

There is another typographical oddity that suggests something went wrong here: the *ch­ōonpu* (long vowel marker) `ー` (for example in はーい or おーいっ) should be *vertical* in vertical writing, but it appears horizontal here.